# Getting value from dropdown list. I am trying to get value of dropdown list using Javascript. It keep returning the value of the first option

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I try to get the selected value of the dropdown. But it keeps returning the first option value although I may choose different values. Is there any error in the code that makes this error?

```html
                <select id="category" name="category">
                    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                    <option value=1>Rock</option>
                    <option value=2>Classical</option>
                    <option value="Country">Country</option>
                    <option value="Folk">Folk</option>
                    <option value="EDM">EDM</option>
                    <option value="Heavy Metal">Heavy Metal</option>
                    <option value="Hip-hop">Hip-hop</option>
                    <option value="Jazz">Jazz</option>
                    <option value="Pop">Pop</option>
                    <option value="Popular">Popular</option>
                    <option value="Rap">Rap</option>
                    <option value="Soul">Soul</option>
                </select>
```

```js
        function Ulog() {
            var select_id = document.getElementById("category");

            select_id.options[select_id.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not listening to change event

try this

```
const select_id = document.getElementById("category");
select_id.addEventListener('change', evt => {
    console.log(select_id.selectedOptions[0].value);
});
```

I hope this will help